# Silverlight MediaElement progressive download timeout?

Tags: c#, silverlight, timeout, mediaelement

I have a MediaElement inside a Silverlight application that runs out of browser and with elevated trust.

To play a video the MediaElement.Source property is set to a URL (http://localhost:4516/video/play for example). The web-server hosts a correct policy file for socket access to the server.

When the request is made ffmpeg transcodes a video file and streams the result to the MediaElement. The media format is wmv and wma wrapped in asf. Since the Content-Length of the resulting stream is unknown the stream is sent using chunked encoding instead.

The MediaElement plays the file however, after 1 minute and 40 seconds, the progressive download is closed by Silverlight. I've tried different videos, different encoding quality and forced slower transmission rates. Each time after 1:40 the download stops. I've used FireFox and Chrome to make sure that the encoding process works correctly.

I'm really stumped, after googling for a long time I can't find any reason for this 1:40 timeout. Anybody have any ideas?